# Accept general HTML element props in TypeScript Astro component

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

Using Astro with TypeScript, I'm creating a reusable UI component. The component is just a wrapper for the `<a>` HTML tag. The problem is I would have to define the interface `Props` with all the general HTML properties for `<a>` element by myself (`href`, `target`, `title`, etc.)

Is there a way to avoid this in Astro by extending a certain interface?

```
---
export interface Props {} // I don't want to define `href`, `target`, etc. by myself here

const props = Astro.props;
---

<a {...props}>
  <slot />
</a>
```

For reference, this is done in React using types such as  `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can extend your component's prop interface using Astro's [Built-in HTML attributes](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/typescript/#built-in-html-attributes) type

```
---
import type { HTMLAttributes } from 'astro/types';

export interface Props extends HTMLAttributes<'a'> {
  // ...
}

const { 
  ...attrs
} = Astro.props
---

<a {...attrs}>
  <slot />
</a>
```